# Find closest points in a polygon

Tags: algorithms, polygons

I have a 2D polygon defined by a list of $n$ points: $A$, $B$, $C$... These points are sorted in clockwise order. Example:

[image]

I would like to find the most performant algorithm to detect all points which are close together (distance < $x$).In the above example, it is $(H, I)$ and $(B, F)$. I could compare each points with all others points and check their distance => complexity $O(n^2)$. Is it possible to have a better performance knowning that points are already sorted in clockwise order ?

Comment: The order in which the input is sorted does not help you. Instead, a plane sweep algorithm might work, since it allows you to report the closest pair of points in $O(n \log{n})$. You probably need to fix the width of the sweep line to $x$, but I haven't really thought about it. 

See https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairPS.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search